# Import single column csv file of stock market tickers into python as a list

Tags: python, pandas, stock, pandas-datareader

I have a csv file of stock market tickers name which I want to import into python as a list in order to use it in `web.DataReader(ticker_list, 'yahoo', start, end)`. Since my csv file is only a single column, is there a efficient way to do this? My list is as simple as below image

[image]

Comment: when I use `pd.read_csv` it turn my list to a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` which is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
import csv

with open('1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
```

Afterwards you could access the lists contents by using something like
`print(data[0])` for an output of `['^GSPC']`.

I hope this helps